# Is it possible to add a custom attribute to a model field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here's my model:

```
def Post(models.Model):
    ...
    video = models.BooleanField(default=False, youtube=False)
```

is it possible to add the `youtube` attribute so I can use it in my template like so:

```
{% if video.youtube %}
    <p>text</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Subclass `BooleanField` with your own `YouTubeField` or something; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-a-field-subclass

Comment: that seems much more complex than it should be. writing:
    
    `video = models.BooleanField(default=False)`
    `youtube = models.BooleanField(default=False)`

seems much easier.

Comment: Well yes, it is more work to create your own field. Alternatively you could just have a URL field, then a property called `is_youtube` which checked the URL contains `youtube.com` or something & returned `True/False`

Comment: as in a model function? (`def is_youtube(self)`...) yeah that would definitely be better I think.

Comment: Do you want a video field to return a video and to say if that video is youtube or something else? Or only want an indicator that a whole post is video?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to know if a video is hosted on YouTube then you'd be better off with a property;

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    video = models.URLField(verbose_name="URL of video")

    @property
    def video_is_youtube(self):
        """ Returns a boolean if the video is hosted on youtube """
        if self.video and "youtube.com" in self.video:
            return True
        return False
```

Then in your templates you can do `{% if post.video_is_youtube %}` to check if a video is hosted on youtube.